# Java reading html file storaged in a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I know very similar question has been asked several times for reading images/txt files & xml files once packaging a project into a JAR file.

But unfortunately all examples and things I read none answers my question and does not seem to work so here is a snip of my code, I am using Eclipse to package the project and it works perfectly fine without exporting to executable jar but when exporting is fails to load / find the html file.

```
        // TODO - failed to open in file when running in JAR
    File filename = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/resource-uk.html").getFile());

    try {
        URL url = new URL( "file:///"+filename);
        html = new JEditorPane( url );
        html.setEditable( false );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(html);
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        html.addHyperlinkListener( this );
    }
    catch( MalformedURLException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "Malformed URL: " + e );
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "IOException: " + e );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line : "File filename = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/resource-uk.html").getFile());"

and use this

URL url = new URL(getClass().getResource("/resource-uk.html").getFile());

and please make sure that path written in "" is case sensitive so please check the file name properly.

Comment: Almost worked... I used the following syntax
<code>
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/license-uk.html");
</code>

This will work again inside Eclipse but now when I export the JAR it opens as plain TXT rather than HTML format

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved by modifying the code listed bellow and also it turns out in Eclipse when exporting to executable-jar I had to select "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".

```
    try {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/license-uk.html");
        JEditorPane html = new JEditorPane();
        html.setPage(url);
        html.setEditable( false );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(html);
        topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        html.addHyperlinkListener( this );

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

include the file/folder containing  the file in your classpath in manifest file

Comment: File is located in the root for the jar

/resource-uk.html


Here is the Matifest

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: smallsimpleapps.com.MainLaunch
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader

Automatically generated by Eclipse